# How to force npm to use the jquery 2.1.1

Tags: jquery, node.js, materialize, pickadate

I am asking this question as a beginner on node-npm. My current node_modules has a query version 2.2.0. But in the same project i am using materialize-css which has a datepicker component.

This component runs on jquery 2.1.1. My question is simple.

How can i remove the current jquery [v 2.2.0] from my node_modules and install jquery version [2.1.1] so that the datepicker component works.

Comment: How about don't use npm and download directly the version you need and put it in your assets by hand?

Comment: In your `package.json`file you can specify which version you'd like to use: `"jquery":"2.1.1",` in the `"dependencies"` portion. Then do a npm install.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Add the specific version to your **`package.json`** :

```
"dependencies": {
    "jquery": "2.1.1"
}
```

Then, **run the following command** :

```
npm update
```

Comment: And then run `nmp install` to install missing packages. Or there's this [npm-install-missing](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-install-missing)  module that handles missing dependencies too.

Comment: My issues relating to this was that i was having my jquery inside "devDependencies" rather than "dependencies". Thanks for noting that!

Answer (score 6):

You can use the npm CLI to install the dependency directly without changing the dependencies yourself in package.json by typing:

`npm install jquery@2.1.1`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for helping out.
I went to my package.json file and added dependency as

```
"dependencies": {
  "jquery": "2.1.1"
}
```

after this I did `sudo npm update` to the existing project and it changed the jquery version to 2.1.1. I assume `sudo npm install` would also have same effect